# Ansible rds 'facts' doesn't return me the ARN

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I need to find the ARN for my Db instance using facts keyword provided at [RDS Module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/rds_module.html). The following is a basic play:

```
- name: Get The RDS Facts from AWS
  rds:
    command: facts
    region: '{{ aws_region }}'
    instance_name: '{{ source_rds_instance_name  }}'
  register: db_facts
```

The play's output:

```
TASK: [read_replica_rds | Get The RDS Facts from AWS] ************************* 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
   "changed":false,
   "instance": {
      "availability_zone":"ap-southeast-2a",
      "backup_retention":7,
      "create_time":1473670897.052,
      "endpoint":"test-for-cross-region.oe451o1vbl45.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
      "id":"test-for-cross-region",
      "instance_type":"db.m3.medium",
      "iops":null,
      "maintenance_window":"wed:14:00-wed:14:30",
      "multi_zone":false,
      "port":3306,
      "replication_source":null,
      "status":"available",
      "username":"root",
      "vpc_security_groups":"sg-d3b9e7b7"
   }
}
```

Since the ARN is not provided in the output, how to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is no ARN property for [DBInstance](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/rds.html#boto.rds.dbinstance.DBInstance) object in boto.

Why don't you just [construct](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) the ARN knowing the instance name?

```
arn:aws:rds:<region>:<account-id>:db:<db-instance-name>
```

Comment: how do i get the <accoun-id> ?

Comment: @Kittystone for one time shot you can look it in the AWS console or get via AWS CLI `aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query Account`. If you want to get it dynamically from Ansible, you should construct some modules chain... (I don't see an easy way).

Comment: Thanks mate. i will go with your option to do so